# Assignment Problem with Non assignable cell

Tags: assignment-problem

I have question for you guys. In this question is there something else that I should do ? When i try to solve with the way that my professor thought , its unsolveable. What should i do to solve this ?

'*' means there will be no assignment for that person to that job

[image: '*' means there will be no assignment for that person to that job]

[image: thats my progress]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure what your question is.  I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve.  Can you state the problem in English?  We are an English-language site, so we require the question to be written in English.  I apologize for the extra work.

Comment: @D.W. It's just a classic problem that known as Assignment Problem. I searched on internet and my professors lecture notes but there are no examples with '*' element so i couldnt solve it. I need to find min and max Assignment cost